# MvxImageView, can't bind ImageUrl to local resource

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross 3.0.14 with Xamarin.Android.

I have an MvxImageView that I can get to display a particular local graphics resource if I specify the image directly (without binding) using android:src:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="75dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/Card_kh"/>
```

But I can't get the same image to show up using local:MvxBind:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="75dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  local:MvxBind="ImageUrl 'res:Card_kh'"/>
```

This does not work.  MvxAndroidLocalFileImageLoader.LoadResourceBitmap logs a trace message indicating that 'Card_kh' was not a known drawable name.  It's encouraging that it got that far -- at least I know that the intended consumer of this information did get it.  But apparently I have not provided that information in the correct format.

Taking it one step further, my actual goal is to have my ViewModel determine what resource should be used, e.g.

```
class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
  public string SomeImagePath { get { return "res:Card_kh"; } }
}
```

and

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="75dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  local:MvxBind="ImageUrl SomeImagePath"/>
```

What do I need to do to have an MvxImageView bind to a view-model determined local resource image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was only capitalization in the resource name.  Although the image filename starts with a capital C, and the android:src attribute works with a capital C, the MvxBind of ImageUrl requires a lowercase c:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="75dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  local:MvxBind="ImageUrl 'res:card_kh'"/>
```

This also solves the problem when the source of the ImageUrl value is a viewmodel property:

```
class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
  public string SomeImagePath { get { return "res:card_kh"; } }
}
```

and

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="75dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  local:MvxBind="ImageUrl SomeImagePath"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is not working anymore since MVVMCross v6.0.0.

As described here https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-60 MvxImageView has been removed from the API.

The newest alternative is now https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/MvvmCross.

This nuget package "Xamarin.FFImageLoading" must be added in order to make the code below work.

```
<ffimageloading.cross.MvxCachedImageView
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="75dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  local:MvxBind="ImagePath SomeImagePath"/>
```