# Can I use MvxImageView with view model bitmaps?

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have png images stored in a remote SQL Server database as image field types. I aim to download and store them in a local SQL Lite database as blob types. The app runs in an occasionally connected manner so cannot grab the images via URL.

The image will ultimately be a property of a view model. How do do I bind to this from my MvxImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at MvvmCross N+1 N=14 where Stuart shows how to bind the MvxImageView to a byte array using the MvxInMemoryImageValueConverter.

http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n14-adding-picturechooser-and-file.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look. Sounds like just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason why would you want to keep image files in database?

I would save the files on the Android file system, it's more efficient. Use database just to keep path references to the files, if necessary.

You can then easily bind MvxImageView to the file:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="75dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  local:MvxBind="ImageUrl SomeImagePath"/>
```

Similar question here:
[MvxImageView, can't bind ImageUrl to local resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940360/mvximageview-cant-bind-imageurl-to-local-resource)

Comment: I have seen several suggestions along these lines but I don't know how to download and save to the local file system. Plus it would have to be done in a cross platform manner. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question was not how you download files, but how you bind MvxImageView. For downloading, you can use HttpClient: var buffer = await new HttpClient().GetByteArrayAsync("http://wwww.myserver.com/1.png"); you then need to write the buffer to a file